# Excel cell custom format

Tags: microsoft-excel, cell-format

I cannot find the way, how to create custom cell format in Excel.

For example, I have value 3.5555, which is displayed as 3.6.
I would like to get displayed 35 555.
If I insert number 5 ... I would like to see 50 000. If I enter number 5.1 .... I would like to see 51 000.
I would like to basically display the values in 10 000.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Custom format can change decimal separator or remove/hide it, but cannot move it (the only exclusion is percent format which moves it 2 positions left - but the same with 4 positions move not exists).

Comment: Yes, I don't need to move the decimal separator. I think I need to set the conditions like "general" (to show the whole real value) + "conditon to make the value 3.5555 showed as 35 555"

Answer (score 2):

**Create a custom number format**

On the Home tab, in the Number group, click More Number Formats at the bottom of the Number Format list  Format Number box.

- In the Format Cells dialog box, under Category, click Custom.
- In the Type list, select the built-in format that most resembles the
  one that you want to create. For example, 0.00.
- The number format that you select appears in the Type box.
- In the Type box, modify the number format codes to create the exact
  format that you want. For example, 000-000-0000.
- Your changes will not alter the built-in format. Instead, your
  changes create a new custom number format.
- When you have finished, click OK.

**Apply a custom number format**

- Select the cell or range of cells that you want to format.
- On the Home tab, in the Number group, click More Number Formats at
  the bottom of the Number Format list Format Number box.
- In the Format Cells dialog box, under Category, click Custom.
- At the bottom of the Type list, select the built-in format that you
  just created. For example, 000-000-0000.
- The number format that you select appears in the Type box.
- Click OK.

[Create and apply a custom number format](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-and-apply-a-custom-number-format-6c308025-35da-4047-9481-c146a12063df)

Comment: This cannot help to solve OP's problem. Applying such formats will display the value rounded to 4.

Answer (score 1):

Write a macro to split the decimal to a string, eg VBA code:

```
Sub Macro1()

    Range("J4").Select

    Dim cellA As Double
    cellA = Range("K3").Value2
    arr = Split(cellA, ".")

    Dim cellb As String
    cellb = arr(0) & " " & arr(1)

    Range("K4").Value2 = cellb
End Sub
```

---

VB Editor (Alt + F11)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, unfortunatelly I have no idea, how to use this.

Comment: Doesn't mean it's not the right answer. It would work as an answer...